# Spring Boot & Hibernate inside VPS 512M

Tags: java, spring

I have simple site and want to deploy it at VPS with 512M ram.

At all, I have Cent OS + nginx + Postgresql and it takes 150M.

And, JRE8 + my project (including app server - Tomcat) tskes 254M.

htop show that I have at server 466M, so free only 62M but its yellow color in htop.

I run Java process via: nohup java -Xmx64m -jar some.jar &

Also, at application.properties I define: server.tomcat.max-threads = 10

SO QUESTION: how can I setup my site for use 180M instead 250M, so that I have at least a little memory left? What can I do? Change app server? Any settings?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are using Java 8 which has slightly different options for configuring memory usage.

Here is an example of memory consumption options in Java 8 (taken from [here](https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx)):

```
-XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=64M -XX:CodeCacheExpansionSize=1M -XX:CodeCacheMinimumFreeSpace=1M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200M
-XX:MinMetaspaceExpansion=1M -XX:MaxMetaspaceExpansion=8M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=200M
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=96M
-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=256M
-Xss1024K
```

Comment: Nice page and I discover that settings asap. But its asks more questions: where is permgen? But much more I interested to known practices. What keys usually tuned which deploy app?